# How to create subclasses in OWL using OWL 2

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

How can I create subclasses using owl api? The following has been generated using protege.

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/muz_a/ontologies/2016/diseasesymptomogy-9#dizziness">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/muz_a/ontologies/2016/diseasesymptomogy-9#symptom"/>
        <rdfs:label>dizziness</rdfs:label>
 </owl:Class>`
 <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/muz_a/ontologies/2016/diseasesymptomogy-9#dizziness">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/muz_a/ontologies/2016/diseasesymptomogy-9#symptom"/>
        <rdfs:label>dizziness</rdfs:label>
 </owl:Class>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What didn't work about it?  The OWL-API is pretty well documented, so I assume you're running into some particular problem?

Comment: Reading the OWL API documentation and examples is the way to go...

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor im not getting an appropriate output as the one above im rather having of this type


subclassof
                class #a
                class #b
subclassof

even if im using this:

 OWLAxiom axiom_spec = df.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(clsA, clsA_spec);

which should be working fine. right??

Comment: Without showing the code, how can we know what you're doing?!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation available [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation) has examples on how to add, delete and save changes to an ontology.

https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version4/contract/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/examples/Examples.java

```
@Test
public void shouldAddAxiom() throws Exception {
    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    IRI ontologyIRI = IRI.create("http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/testont.owl");
    IRI documentIRI = IRI.create("file:/tmp/MyOnt.owl");
    SimpleIRIMapper mapper = new SimpleIRIMapper(ontologyIRI, documentIRI);
    manager.getIRIMappers().add(mapper);
    OWLOntology ontology = manager.createOntology(ontologyIRI);
    OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
    OWLClass clsA = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#A"));
    OWLClass clsB = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#B"));
    OWLAxiom axiom = factory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(clsA, clsB);
    AddAxiom addAxiom = new AddAxiom(ontology, axiom);
    manager.applyChange(addAxiom);
    manager.saveOntology(ontology);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addSubClass() throws OWLOntologyCreationException, OWLOntologyStorageException  {
    OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File("pathToFile");
    OWLDataFactory dataFactory = OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory();

    OWLClass parentC = dataFactory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(baseIRI, "parent");
    OWLClass childC = dataFactory.getOWLClass(IRI.create(baseIRI, "child");
    axiom = dataFactory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(childC, parentC);

    Axiom addAxiom = new AddAxiom(ontology, axiom);

    manager.applyChange(addAxiom);
    manager.saveOntology(ontology);
}
```